# dotnet-SonarScanner - unable to analyze C# files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am executing Sonar in GitHub using SonarScanner - `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.2.2` - and it is providing a result.

**SonarQube: Community version 7.9.4**

**dotnet-SonarScanner: 4.10.0 / 5.2.2** (tried with both and earlier was working with 4.10.0)

The following shell script I'm using to execute the sonar as follow:

**PowerShell Script**

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /key:$projectKey `
    /d:sonar.log.level="DEBUG" `
    /v:"$(gitversion /nofetch /showvariable AssemblySemVer)" `
    /d:sonar.links.scm=$repository `
    /d:sonar.scm.provider="git" `
    /d:sonar.scm.revision="$(git rev-parse HEAD)" `
    /d:sonar.buildString="$(gitversion /nofetch /showvariable NuGetVersion)" `
    /d:sonar.host.url="https://ccq.svc.myorg.com" `
    /d:sonar.login=$token `
    /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$pwd\CodeCoverageReports\CoverageReport.xml" `
    /d:sonar.cs.xunittest.reportsPaths="$pwd\TestResults\TestResults.xml"
    
& $msbuild $solutionName /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build -maxcpucount:1 /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary
    
dotnet sonarscanner end "/d:sonar.login=$token"
```

But when a result is updated in SonarQube it is not analyzing the `C#` files and analyzing the `XML` & `JS` files only.

I have crossed-checked in **SonarQube > Project > Aministration > General Settings** and there is no files excluded.

***Can you pls share what am I missing here?***

Comment: Since you are using target build instead of rebuild, are you sure that the software is actually built? If the software was already built, target build will do nothing and SonarQube will not detect any files.

Comment: @raspy: I tried with rebuild and still no luck.

Comment: If you are using `dotnet sonarscanner` you are supposed to build your project using `dotnet build`, not `msbuild`. For MSBuild you would need to use `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin`. Consult the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/#header-3).

Comment: Is it because of some version change? Because with same settings it was working fine earlier approx. 1 month back. And sorry I forgot to mention this part in details - I have tried it with `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe` but it didn't work with it either.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on line:

```
gitversion /nofetch /showvariable NuGetVersion
```

there is no such executable, probably: `gitversion`

the correct line is:

```
git version /nofetch /showvariable NuGetVersion
```

resulting in string like this:

```
git version 2.42.0.windows.2
```

I think that if ever SonarQube is running this string it will definetely should fail build cause it will not find requested command in a command line..

Also, try to run `command -v gitversion` to see whether this command exists on a system or not